# Unable to activate virtualenv via bash script

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm running a project inside a virtualenv in python. Here's the path to the virtualenv.

```
~/iss/issp/bin
```

The problem is when I try to run the activate script with:

```
source activate
```

it throws the following error.

```
:~/iss/issp/bin$ source activate
: command not found
bash: activate: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'ash: activate: line 4: `deactivate () {
```

Here's the code inside the script:

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly

deactivate () {
    unset pydoc

    # reset old environment variables
    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH" ] ; then
        PATH="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME" ] ; then
        PYTHONHOME="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "$BASH" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] ; then
        hash -r 2>/dev/null
    fi

    if [ -n "$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1" ] ; then
        PS1="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    if [ ! "$1" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/pablo/issp"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
# this will fail if PYTHONHOME is set to the empty string (which is bad anyway)
# could use `if (set -u; : $PYTHONHOME) ;` in bash
if [ -n "$PYTHONHOME" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="$PYTHONHOME"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        PS1="$PS1"
    else
    if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
        # special case for Aspen magic directories
        # see http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/
        PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
    fi
    fi
    export PS1
fi

alias pydoc="python -m pydoc"

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "$BASH" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] ; then
    hash -r 2>/dev/null
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had the same problem, and decided to do `hexdump -C bin/activate` to figure out. Turns out my bin/activate file had CR/LF line endings instead of just CR, changing them with `(tr -d '\r' < bin/activate) > bin/activate`fixed my problem.

Comment: a little more explanation on how to do this `(tr -d '\r' < bin/activate) > bin/activate` maybe?

Comment: @Arturo that is a shell command, copy-paste it in your shell and it will likely work.

Comment: It removes entire content of file

Comment: as nish comments the command deletes the content of the file for me.

Comment: I did this, which seemed to work: 
$ cd .venv/Scripts/ <newline>
$ cp -p activate activate.abo <newline>
$ (tr -d '\r' < activate.abo) > activate

Answer (score 25):

The issue is that the `activate` script has Windows line endings. We can confirm this by running the below command on the command line.

```
$ file activate
```

which returns

```
activate: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

CRLF line terminators means windows line endings.

Therefore we need to convert them to Unix line endings so that we can `source` the file.

We have a few of options

1. `dos2unix activate` - (this edits the file in place)
2. `sed -i 's/\r$//' activate` (also edits the file in place)
3. `mv activate activate_with_windows_line_endings && (tr -d '\r' < activate_with_windows_line_endings ) > activate` here we we just remove any occurrence of `\r` and the original file is preserved.
4. Open the file in your favourite text editor. Most will have a way to both show the current line endings of the file (bottom right of image below) and a way to convert them to Unix line endings (In Notepad++  we go to `Edit → EOL Conversion → Unix (LF)` and then save. Here is a screenshot of how to do it in Notepad++
   [image]

#### Finally

Now `source activate` should work.

Comment: Although I personally would recommend using WSL and avoiding all these windows issues.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. +1 from me

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem using VS Code and the `venv` package from python's standard library, since I use bash for my default terminal.

Bash scripts should always use LF instead of CRLF line endings. This is [now fixed](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/pull/1924) for the python `virtualenv` package, but it's still an issue with `venv`.

As described here, https://bugs.python.org/issue43437, `venv` copies its `activate` script template in binary mode when creating new virtual environments. Therefore we only need to convert the original to Unix line endings, using any of [Mark's methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61840516/1739107) above.

The activate script template is located here: `<python3_root>/Lib/venv/scripts/common/activate`

To fix it in place: `sed -i 's/\r$//' activate`

As long as that file keeps its LF line endings, new virtual environments created with `venv` should have viable activation scripts.

Comment: The `sed` line worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have an alias in your .bashrc file, that's why deactivate takes like the command, not like a function

instead

```
deactivate() {
```

use this

```
function deactivate() {
```